# wsdl client with Qt

Tags: soap, qt4, wsdl

i've problem when create a wsdl client using Qt framework. wsdl file is from ejbca wsdl. my program is client for ejbca server and using wsdl to access ejbca services.but i don't know how to handle this. plz give me some suggestion to do...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [Qt Soap Support](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsoap/) can not generate code from wsdl. You can use [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) to generate code using your WSDL and use it from your Qt application.

Comment: Great tip about gSOAP, looks useful

Answer (score 1):

[Staff](http://code.google.com/p/staff/) is a web service framework based on Apaches AXIS2/C. There is [an example](http://code.google.com/p/staff/wiki/ExampleCreatingCppClientFromWsdl) on how to write a Qt C++ Client based on WSDL using this framework.